# $watch within a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this shared_service factory that is used between my menu and other elements of the page.

```
angular.module('shared_service', []).
    factory('Shared', function($scope){
        var shared_service = {
            something: 'something',
            something_else: 'something_else'
        };

        //I want to watch something so I can change something_else
        //$scope.$watch('shared_service.something', function(){
        //    something_else something_else + 1
        //}
        return shared_service;
});
```

I know I could attach the watcher elsewhere like in a controller, but to me it feels like I should put it here.  Is this possible to put it here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `$watch` from the `$rootScope`, but I believe as it's not in a controller you have to watch the return value of a function... something like this should work:

```
angular.module('shared_service', []).
  factory('Shared', function($rootScope){
    var shared_service = {
        something: 'something',
        something_else: 'something_else'
    };

    $rootScope.$watch(function() {
      return shared_service.something;
    }, function () {
             shared_service.something_else = shared_service.something_else + 1;
    });
    return shared_service;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly, question. I know this works because of closure, but you are able to watch shared_service.something because it is an object attribute and not a variable correct?  As in I wouldn't be able to watch shared_service if it was just a string.

Comment: I *should* work when watching a function... but I'm not positive